# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when loading UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I'm quite new to the iOS platform, but am already an experimented Android dev.

I'm experiencing a weird issue in Swift, we cannot reproduce in Objectice-C. We are designing our interfaces by hand, without using the Interface Builder, to have more flexibility.

We are getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the mentioned line in our custom UIViewController. While the question seems to have been asked many times on StackOverflow, I either haven't found a solution written in Swift or a  solution which was working properly and a really similar problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var logo:UIImage = UIImage(named: "sgLogo")! --> EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    var sgLogo:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: logo)

    // other UI elements, + constraints
    [...]
}
```

The only element I get is a stack trace, the debugger view in the bar below Xcode is empty. According to that stack trace, the UIImage seems to be instantiated: presence of a memory address.

The sgLogo image is a png image located in the project folder structure not in Images.xcassets. I tried to specify it in the images assets, but I'm still experimenting the same issue. Specifying the extension or not does not help either.

I can provide more code snippets if you want.

Comment: Just add the image to your image asset and mame it sgLogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to solve the issue. I was overriding the `loadView` method of my `UIViewController`, but not calling the parent method. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your image can not be found. Check the picture's target. For now you can fix the issue by removing the exclamation mark. If you force unwrap like this and the image is not there, your app will crash. So you can do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var logo = UIImage(named: "sgLogo") 
    if let logo = logo { 
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: logo) 
    } else { 
        //image is nil 
    }

    // other UI elements, + constraints
    [...]
}
```

Comment: You should just use if let to make sure it is not nil. Removing the ! Doesn't solve the problem

Comment: The picture is really present in the project and I already removed the exclamation mark to make sure, but in such a case xcode refuses to compile with the following error message: "Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped."

Comment: wget UIImage(named:) it is only for images located in your image asset

Comment: @wget you should use let not var

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus, yes this is true for the `UIImageView`. It should be declared as a `let`. But what if he wants to chage the logo? Without a context `var` is ok.

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus, UIImage(named:) searches for images in your app's bundle.

Comment: Well I cannot even make the nil check properly. Do you have a working example? The latter is not working ans still crashing on the same line:
    var logo:UIImage? = UIImage(named: "sgLogo")
        if (logo == nil) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
        }

Comment: Try this: `var logo = UIImage(named: "sgLogo")
    if let logo = logo {
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    } else { exit(EXIT_FAILURE) }`

Comment: @flashadvanced I need to make a check to nil, because I have several lines after that makes call to that logo to add constraint, and I don't want to add all that code into the condition.
I want to detect the issue, then quit. And the code you provided to me doesn't compile. I cannot assign two values to the same variable considered as a constant the line after.

Comment: @wget I recommend you create 3 images.png and corresponding 2x 3x select those 3 files and drag them together to your image asset

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus This is what I have now in my Images.xcassets. The image is available in 3 versions.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Sorry, I cannot provide a picture inside my question since I'm < 10 rep points. But here is a screenshot of the bug I have --> https://goo.gl/SjopIZ

Comment: What about the Images.xcassets screen shot?

Comment: @wget, can you check something. Open your project's settings and see if your image is under `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Comment: @flashadvanced The Images.xcassets is well defined there.

Comment: @wget, I am talking about the image itself. Did you check for it in the bundle resources as I told you?

Comment: @flashadvanced. Like i said, the image itself was not in the `Copy Bundle Resources` property.
On the other side, I succeeded to solve the issue. I was overriding the `loadView` method of my `UIViewController`, but not calling the parent method. Problem solved.